# how to make FloatingActionButtn filled with image?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

when I set Image for FloatingActionButton it will be margin at all directions .so I want the ActionButton to be filled with image without any margin.

[image]

Comment: set background to FloatingActionButton.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute

```
android:src="YOUR_DRAWABLE"
```

in your `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` block of XML layout.

Also in you `styles.xml`, under the style you are using (normally it is `AppTheme`) use

```
<item name="colorAccent">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to achieve. Use this code.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
   android:background="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
    android:src="@drawable/zvam" />
```

You will get something like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC4xg.png

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I do not answer your question directly (I would comment if I could), but I don't think that this is a good idea.

It seems to me that you just want to have a done/check-image on the FAB. If that's the case, you should use the "done" icon from google's material-icons page: https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_done

Also, have a look at google's designguidelines for FABs: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html.